# Impossible to make the universal link work

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

I'm setting up a universal link from my application. However, when I click on the link that redirects to my application I have a **page not found**.
I think for now that the problem comes from the file (json) `apple-app-site-association`.

I followed the apple documentation.I enter the domain name in these website, result:

- http://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/#resultsbox :
  [image]

*In this one everything is fine, I am told that everything is OK*.

- https://limitless-sierra-4673.herokuapp.com :

[image]

*On the other hand on the second site, he asks me to change the content-type, I wonder if my problem comes from there or not because I did not find anything in the doc is it therefore essential for the universal link.*

In addition, how to be sure using the xcode debugger that the application is well configured for the universal link. From the android side to the installation of the application it is enough to look for the domain name to see if yes or no the universal link is well taken into account. Is it the same process for ios?